# Access field in view's model inside tree view

Tags: odoo-13, qweb

I am trying to modify an existing view, and add a column to a tree.

The view's model is `stock.picking`, and the tree view's model is `stock.move`.

The field I am trying to add should only be displayed if a certain condition is met. That is, if the `stock.picking` has it's `sale_id` set, then I want to display my field (column) in the tree.

Here is the code edited for brevity:

```
<form string="Transfer">
    ....
    <field name="move_ids_without_package" mode="tree,kanban" attrs="{'readonly': ['&amp;', ('state', '=', 'done'), ('is_locked', '=', True)]}" context="{'default_company_id': company_id, 'picking_type_code': picking_type_code, 'default_picking_id': id, 'form_view_ref':'stock.view_move_form', 'address_in_id': partner_id, 'default_picking_type_id': picking_type_id, 'default_location_id': location_id, 'default_location_dest_id': location_dest_id}">
        <tree decoration-danger="not parent.immediate_transfer and state != 'done' and quantity_done &gt; reserved_availability and show_reserved_availability" decoration-muted="scrapped == True or state == 'cancel' or (state == 'done' and is_locked == True)" string="Stock Moves" editable="bottom">
        ....
        **MY CONDITIONAL FIELD GOES HERE***
```

In my view, I inherit and modify the one above:

```
<field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="(//field[@name='product_id'])[1]" position="before">
            <field name="sale_id"/>
            <field name="co7_so_line_number" readonly="1" attrs="{'invisible': [('sale_id', '=', False)]}"/>
        </xpath>
</field>
```

This doesn't work. I think the issue is that the 'context' of the tree view is `stock.move` and that `sale_id` is a field of `stock.picking`. How can I access the "outer" model (`stock.picking`) from within the tree view (without editing the parent view, of course)?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that you can use the "magic" keyword `parent` to access fields in the parent model (i.e. the model of the form containing the tree view).

```
<field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="(//field[@name='product_id'])[1]" position="before">
            <field name="sale_id"/>
            <field name="co7_so_line_number" readonly="1" attrs="{'invisible': [('parent.sale_id', '==', False)]}"/>
        </xpath>
</field>
```

(and I was missing an '=')